# how to highlight color in <ul> when its child is clicked?

Tags: css

i have many links in left side of my site,so i have a list like this

- home
- categories
- aboutus
- contactus

when i click on

home

the page is submitted and then loads.after loading i need to

highlight home list...similar to others that clicked list should be selected after loading.

how to do that???

Comment: what languages are you comfortable with ? php,html,js??

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I normally use:

1. Use something like an `.active` class on the item on it´s page, so the `home` link would have the `.active` class on the home page;
2. Use a class on every item (`.home` on the home link, `.contact` on the contact link, etc.) and give the body of every page a specific id or class as well (`#home` on home, etc.). The you can style the links uniquely on each page using stuff like `#home .home, #contact .contact {}`, etc.